# Create a fully working jaas_config file in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, jaas

my problem is that I am trying to create a working jaas_config file in Weblogic.
As long as I have one line in the config file, it seems to be okay.

```
MyServices {
com.example.myservices required;};
```

But when I type in more lines I always get

```
No Configuration was registered that can handle the configuration named MyServices
```

This is my full file:

```
MyServcies {
com.example.myservices required
debug=true
programName=My First Program
db=TestDb
port666;};
```

Are there any things I have to consider when creating this file?
Are new line feeds not allow, do I have to put more words into apostrophe or something like that?

I was able to solve the problem with many arguments now, put it in apostrophe and not comma separated.

But port is still not working.

I could not find anything in Weblogic documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem after having asked, the same old thing.

Values with more content have to be put into apostrophe, as an example:

```
key="a, b, c"
```

keys with numbers must also be put in apostrophe, as an example:

```
key="888"
```

Comment: Did you set the jaas configuration file path via the system property of "java.security.auth.login.config"?  Where did you set the application name(MyServices) on the Weblogic?